# mysql select sum, max, and another column value at the same row which the max value stays

Tags: mysql, sql

Sample table:

```
uid time_stp                traf
1   2016-01-13 00:00:00     6
1   2016-01-13 05:00:00     8
1   2016-01-13 10:00:00     14
1   2016-01-13 15:00:00     26
1   2016-01-13 20:00:00     42
...
```

My SQL:

```
select
    uid,
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(time_stp)/3600) * 3600) as tm,
    sum(traf),
    max(traf),
    -- xxx as max_traf_time
from
    group_by_time_range
group by
    uid, tm;
```

I want to sum the `traf` hourly, and find the max `traf` with corresponding `time_stp` in each hour section. How could I use a single SQL statement to finish this stuff.

Comment: You would like to sum hourly, it means that these 2016-01-13 10:00:00 2016-02-11 10:00:00  should sum up?

Comment: What's your error? Also, you need to copy TM column to your group by, you can't use it on this level since it doesn't exsist yet. Either Rap it with another select or copy the calculation to the group by

Comment: @SzymonRoziewski [2016-01-13 00:00:00, 2016-01-13 01:00:00) will sum up as "2016-01-13 00:00:00".

Comment: @sagi No error there. I mean I want an extra column which is the value of `time_stp` at the same row where found the `max(traf)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tryed

```
select
    T1.uid,
    from_unixtime(floor(unix_timestamp(time_stp)/3600) * 3600) as tm,
    sum(traf),
    (
     SELECT max(traf)
     FROM group_by_time_range T2
     WHERE T2.uid = T1.uid
    ) as Max_Traf,
    (
     SELECT time_stp
     FROM group_by_time_range T3
     WHERE traf = Max_Traf
    ) as max_traf_time
from
    group_by_time_range T1
group by
    uid, tm;
```

Comment: It will produce `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Max_Traf' in 'where clause'`.